# How to split the site's layout without damaging this layout?

Tags: theme-development, customization, page-template

I have a site: http://roomble.com and I need to migrate it to wordpress (to be particular, I need in the nearest perspective it's plugins and ability to login thgrough the social networks via wordpress plugins)

I ought to split this design up into header.php, content.php and footer.php without any damaging the content and layout. We don't need to display any posts yet so instead of them should be added a placeholder like an arbitrary article.

Now we're using the Bitrix as a CMS, headroom.js, several inner Bitrix templates which form the current design and they're kind of bulky so we wouldn't like to rewrite all of them.

Is it possible to port this site on wordpress this way as I described?

Comment: Yes , you can convert site in wordpress and can depart site section as you mentioned like header , content , sidebar and footer. There will be minor layout css issues will arise but will be easily manageable.

Comment: Could you recommend any article or tutorial about how to migrate sites the way that I mentioned above?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Better thing is that if you have all pages in html format of you current site , following will help you to convert html to wordpress as per your given partition :

```
http://www.wpexplorer.com/create-wordpress-theme-html-1/
```

Comment: Yes, I have a full archive of html/css/js files which was used with the former version of the site. Another question: is it possible to place all these files in the root of the wp directory and activate only those functions of wordpress what I need. Now I'm trying to add "require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' )" in index.php (former index.html of my site) but what I see is just a blank page when I'm trying to get it.

Comment: Yes you can make all things dynamic and then can hide/disable which you do not want to show..About blank page I think its missing some things or improper configuration.

Comment: Yes, it's working now, but how can I add plugin to the index page placed in the root of WordPress with included ./wp-blog-header.php and disabled themes? For example, I need to add authorization via social networks using menu inside of the index.php file: https://github.com/stanislas-prime/SocialAuther

Comment: Now you will need to do things via custom php/wordpress code.

Comment: You know, the bigger part of your answers get auto flagged as low quality or by others as low quality. I personally have handled a lot of your posts flagged as low quality. Please stop posting links as answers. Continuous flags, downvotes and poor quality answers **will** get your account automatically blocked by the system, not the community or moderators. Please start keeping that in mind